# ASP.NET Multicast UdpClient problems

Tags: asp.net, permissions, udpclient

I'm trying to have my ASP.NET app listen for multicast UDP broadcasts. Unfortunately, I seem to be stuck in a bind due to permissions/api issues.

The problem is that I need to allow multiple instances of an application to listen to the same IP/Port since multiple spin-ups of the ASP.NET application will occur. To do this, the SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress must be set to true. The problem is that this requires administrative privileges that my ASP.NET app should not have.

Here's the code:

```
public static void Listen(int port)
{
   var groupAddress = IPAddress.Parse("224.10.10.10");
   var endPoint = new IPEndPoint(groupAddress, port);
   var client = new UdpClient();

   client.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
   client.Client.Bind(new IPEndpoint(IPAddress.Any, port)); // Error thrown here       
   client.JoinMulticastGroup(groupAddress);       

   var udpState = new UdpState() { Client = client, EndPoint = endPoint };
   client.BeginReceive(OnMessageReceived, udpState); // OnMessageReceived code omitted
}
```

Comment: What port number are you using? Not sure about windows but unix systems usually require admin rights when binding ports 1024 and under but not anything above 1024.

Comment: The ports are high, 65008ish. It's a limitation of the framework it seems. If I do: var client = new UdpClient(port), it doesn't require admin rights, but then it also can't be used with the ReuseAddress socket option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems as though this isn't possible without administrative rights. If anyone has any other ideas, I'd love to hear them.

Answer (score 0):

```
client.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
```

Comment: It'd be more helpful to the OP and to future readers if you explained why they should do this.